# Setting up double integrals in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently studying double integrals in polar coordinates and I'd like clarification on some issues I'm having.

Suppose I have a disk centered at $(1,0)$ with radius 1. How do I set up the integrals by
(a) slicing up the disk where $\theta$ is constant
(b) slicing up the disk wheere $r$ is constant.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *set up integrals*?

Comment: I want to write the area enclosed by the disk as a double integral

Comment: So you have to know how to describe the disc in polar coordinates. $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ and $0\leq r\leq 1$. Now integrate the constant function equal to one.

Comment: Sorry, my comment above is to disc centered at the origin.

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense. Do you mean you want to set this up in both orders $dr\,d\theta$ and $d\theta\,dr$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a big hint: Show that the circle is given in polar coordinates by the equation $r=2\cos\theta$. What is the interval on which $\theta$ lives? A picture will help.

**EDIT:** Now, as with cartesian coordinates, for any $-\pi/2\le \theta\le\pi/2$, $r$ goes from what to what? And, since you insist, for any $0\le r\le 2$, then $\theta$ goes from what to what? In both cases, the equation I gave you in the first paragraph is relevant.

Comment: $\theta$ will lie between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi / 2$

Comment: Yes. So what is the integral $\int\int ? \,dr\,d\theta$? By the way, that's the order of integration I always recommend unless the region is (a portion of) a disk centered at the origin.

Comment: ok. thanks. shouldn't the circle be $r= 2 \cos \theta$? What if I

Comment: Yes, you are right! Sloppy mental error on my part. Go finish now!

Comment: Ok. as $-\pi /2 \le \theta \le \pi /2$, $ 0\le r \le 2\cos \theta$? I'm struggling to find the second part for when $r$ is between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: Yes. Pictures do help. Draw a circle of radius $r\le 2$ centered at the origin. What portion of it is inside your given circle? That is, what values of $\theta$ keep you inside?

Comment: I'm not sure if what I did is right, but I got $\theta$ between $-\cos^{-1} r /2$ and $\cos^{-1} r/2$. I solved for $\theta$ in the equation $r=2\cos \theta$.

Comment: Yup, you've got it. But please avoid that order of integration in real life :P

Comment: @Gorg: If you're satisfied at this point, please accept the answer so that this will not stay on the "unanswered" list. Best of luck!